# How can i download a sample xlsx file from public resource folder in React js

Tags: reactjs, download, xlsx

I'm trying to download a sample xlsx file from public folder in React js in the following way

```
<a
  href={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/my-file.xlsx"}
  download={"my-file.xlsx"}
>
    Download file
</a>
```

i am stuck at this. downloading this way works locally, but when deployed to public, it fails and instead downloads just an empty corrupted file. Any ideas on that ?

Why the file is being corrupted on the server, although it works fine locally?

Answer (score 1):

you should use relative path of file for href,

ex: `href={"../../assets/files/my-file.xlsx"}`
and dont do this "`download={"my-file.xlsx"}`"
instead write `download={true}` or only download

Comment: Thanks, the issue has been resolved, it was due to redirection headers permissions on the amplify